# New versions of TeamSpeak on ARM (Raspberry Pi) using QEMU user mode crash

Tags: debian, qemu, emulator, x86, teamspeak

With a help of a friend we have successfully run **TeamSpeak** server which has no source code and no binary for `armhf` **on raspberry pi 3** using **QEMU** in user mode. We followed partially this guide:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215864/running-x86-binaries-on-armv7/215874?noredirect=1#comment591844_215874

Some Infos:

```
QEMU version: 2.8 build from source configured like this (./configure --target-list=i386-linux-user).
TeamSpeak version: x86-3.0.10.1
```

**The problem comes when I try to run newer versions of TeamSpeak like 2.0.12.4 or the latest TS version**. When I start TS it starts doing something (Some of TeamSpeak output comes to the screen) but after a couple of seconds it crashes with this error:

> ```
> qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
> ```

```
root@teamspeak:/opt/teamspeak3-server_linux_x86# ./ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh
2017-01-09 19:14:40.895673|INFO    |ServerLibPriv |   |TeamSpeak 3 Server 3.0.13.6 (2016-11-08 08:48:33)
2017-01-09 19:14:40.928272|INFO    |ServerLibPriv |   |SystemInformation: Linux 4.4.34-v7+ #930 SMP Wed Nov 23 15:20:41 GMT 2016 i686 Binary: 32bit
2017-01-09 19:14:40.930775|WARNING |ServerLibPriv |   |The system locale is set to "C" this can cause unexpected behavior. We advice you to repair your locale!
2017-01-09 19:14:41.002472|INFO    |DatabaseQuery |   |dbPlugin name:    SQLite3 plugin, Version 3, (c)TeamSpeak Systems GmbH
2017-01-09 19:14:41.050215|INFO    |DatabaseQuery |   |dbPlugin version: 3.11.1
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
Segmentation fault
```

I am not sure where that error comes from.

I have to mention that I tried an older version of QEMU (the one in the repositories which is from the middle ages, **version 1.2), and it could run both the newer and the old versions** of TS (but they crash after some minutes which makes it **no choice**).

The dependencies I installed: `libglib2.0-dev libfdt-dev libpixman-1-dev zlib1g-dev binfmt-support libc6:i386`.

I have also to mention that I am running everything in `Docker container`.

I really appreciate any help to solve that problem to be able to run the latest versions of TS.

Comment: To my knowledge, the latest version of Teamspeak is TS3, which is version 3.0.13.6 (server). I'd advise you to contact Teamspeak directly, but I'm not sure they still support Teamspeak 2. As for the segmentation fault, I've seen it in the client before when attempting various tasks, though this one seems bit related. Is there any reason you're attempting to install TS2 instead of TS3?

Comment: @Dooley_labs I am not trying to use TS2, it is TS3, you can see that from the log

Comment: My mistake, it must have been a typo in the bolded line with the versioning. I missed the binary's name. I'm still investigating if there's a better method to debug this error for you in hopes you may get it to work. Segmentation fault isn't a very descriptive error at all.

Comment: @Dooley_labs, Thank you, actually I tried to get it work with no success, therefore I let it till some new debugging method or any helpful info comes.